# tvOS: CollectionView bounds perfect on simulator, but out of screen on device

Tags: swift, layout, uicollectionview, tvos

I have a weird issue where the left most and right most cells in a CollectionView are bleeding outside the edge of the screen on my own TV. I already checked the aspect ratio of the TV itself and it doesn't improve, the app grid on the home screen is perfect and when running in the simulator it's also perfect.

Don't have the option to run on another TV.

I am also setting the flowLayout of the CollectionView to manipulate the item size and the interSpacing.

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: (screenWidth/5), height: (screenWidth/6)*1.5)
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

The rest is set with auto layout in the interface builder.

Answer (score 3):

Your TV probably has [overscan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overscan) turned on, which means all the content around the edges is getting clipped by the display itself.

You can turn overscan off on your TV (and you should do that anyway, because it's just better that way), but you can't count on all of your users turning it off on their TVs. Your best bet is to avoid putting important content too close to the edge of the screen: keep all the vital things inside the [safe area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_area_(television)).

In tvOS 11, you may want to check out UIView's `safeAreaLayoutGuide` and `safeAreaInsets` properties, which can help you lay your views out inside the safe area.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, currently it's an app that I only use internally (not planning on putting it on the store), but yes I'm using tvOS 11 already so I'll have a look into that